# Amazon ECS capacity provider is not scaling out instance at target_capacity=100

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I have enabled ECS to use capacity provider, here is my configuration details

- Auto-scaling for ECS task min=2, desired=2, max=8 and auto-scaling policy for this tracks CPU utilization at 10%(for validation if task are scaling out and in)
- Auto-scaling group for Capacity-provider with min=1, desired=2, max=4

Initially after deployment 2 ECS task were running on 2 different EC2 instance, then I ran load test to verify if Cluster and ECS task scales as expected but ECS task desired count was changed to 8 and only 4 ECS task were running(which is expected as there are 2 EC2 instance and I use t3.medium(3 ENI) instance with AWSVPC for my deployment ).

Why did the cluster did not scale as there are already 4 task which are in provisioning state capacity provider threshold is at 100?

I'm using terraform to deploy my infrastructure and details for capacity provider is as below,

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "kong" {
  ...
  min_size             = var.asg_min_size
  max_size             = var.asg_max_size
  desired_capacity     = var.asg_desired_capacity
  protect_from_scale_in = true
  tags = [
    {
      "key"                 = "Name"
      "value"               = local.name
      "propagate_at_launch" = true
    },
    {
      "key"                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
      "value"               = ""
      "propagate_at_launch" = true 
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "capacity_provider" {
   name = local.name

   auto_scaling_group_provider {
      auto_scaling_group_arn         = aws_autoscaling_group.kong.arn
      managed_termination_protection = "ENABLED"

      managed_scaling {
           maximum_scaling_step_size = 4
           minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
           status                    = "ENABLED"
           target_capacity           = 100
      }
   }

  
   provisioner "local-exec" {
      when = destroy

      command = "aws ecs put-cluster-capacity-providers --cluster ${self.name} --capacity-providers [] --default-capacity-provider-strategy []"
   }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "kong-reg-proxy" {
  name      = local.name
  capacity_providers = [
    aws_ecs_capacity_provider.capacity_provider.name,
  ]
  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name"        = local.name,
      "Environment" = var.environment,
      "Description" = var.description,
      "Service"     = var.service,
    },
    var.tags
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you go to ECS console, and check your cluster's default capacity provider? Please check that it is your asg, not fargate.

Comment: I verified it is showing my autoscaling group

Comment: Going a step back - can you make it work manually using ECS console?

Comment: Im having the same issue with a similar setup. As soon as I go to < 100% target capacity (i.e. 99% or lower), everything works as expected. This, of course, will cause an extra instance to always stay idle (no tasks running on it).

Comment: Like @Marcin has pointed out can you please check in your AWS console?
Go to your ECS cluster -> your ECS service -> check launch type there. It will be EC2 change it to the Capacity provider strategy and it should work.

Comment: I guess it worked? If yes, I can make an answer based on my comment, if you don't mind?

Comment: Yes it did, you can create an answer.

Comment: We just applied capacity provider with 100% target capacity to our existing ECS cluster. Then the scaling-out of all the services did not work because all the launch types are set to EC2. Changing from 100% to 80% fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the target capacity below 100% is a dirty trick. Having that makes you running few spare EC2 instances. Probably that's what you also may want to have, but this way ECS does not control the EC2 autoscaling.
Most likely you've got the service assigned with a launch_type="EC2", like that

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "foo" {
  ...
  launch_type = "EC2"
  ...
}
```

What you should do instead is to assign a service with a capacity provider strategy so that ECS can manage tasks in PROVISIONING state and populate the `CapacityProviderReservation` metric correctly

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "foo" {
  ...
  capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.foo.name
    weight = 1
  }
  ...
}
```

See the reference for more information https://aws.amazon.com/en/blogs/containers/deep-dive-on-amazon-ecs-cluster-auto-scaling/